# Google Cloud Dataflow handling schema evolution (Addition of columns)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub, apache-beam-io

I have a cloud Pub/Sub instance to which my dataflow is subscribed.
each message includes a primary key column and another random column.
I have to check whether that column exists in my bigquery table, if yes then we simply insert.
If not, I have a method which will alter the table structure.
The main issue is that I want to store the columns in a set object and cache it using shared class.
So whenever a new column arises, the cache is updated and is in sync with all other workers.
Any idea on how to update the cache, or something to start with?

Comment: You can use side inputs for that. You can use a Slowly updating side input pattern check here: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/patterns/side-inputs/. Your side input should be updated regularly with a trigger

Comment: The use case changed, so wont be using it. However, thanks for replying